# How to debug laptop S3 suspend problems on Xen/Fedora?

Tags: suspend, xen

I'm running Qubes, which is basically Xen with a Fedora 25 as dom0. The only thing that does not work properly is when I close the notebook lid or press suspend. When I open the notebook again nothing happens, the keyboard wont even ligth, I have to press power button to restart everything.

I don't know if it has anything related to Xen or simply Fedora. How do I start debugging this?

I tried fedora 30 on this notebook and the suspend works great. It also always worked on all Ubuntu versions I used.

Comment: Have you tried `CTRL+ALT+F2` to see if the text based shell wakes up?